Failing to repartition data with PySpark on HDFS
I have over 7k parquet files in an HDFS dataset, totaling a little under 74 GB. One problem is that the file sizes are quite variable, ranging from 12 KB to 622 MB. So, I'd like to repartition the data to make all the file sizes more equal. So here is the command that I'm using:
(
    df
    .repartition("date", "hour")
    .write
    .partitionBy("date", "hour")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .format("parquet")
    .save(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)
)

Here OUTPUT_DIRECTORY is a URL, e.g., hdfs://192.168.1.60:9000/my_repartitioned_dataset. When I run this, I get several ExecutorLostFailure warnings, followed by some TASK_WRITE_LOST warnings, that were Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing pipeline due to no more good datanoddes being available to try. There are dozens of these statements after which my python script simply exits. Am I doing something wrong here? Am I simply running into the limits of my setup? BTW, my environment is:
1 NameNode - 4 cores, 24 GB RAM
3 DataNode - 8 cores, 24 GB RAM

Apache Spark is running in standalone mode on each of the datanodes.

Why are you trying to do this operation in one go in pyspark? The ideal way would be to determine the average_filesize. Then read in files and accumulate them till the total rows file size count > average_filesize (or equivalent to average num_rows say 10k rows) and then write it to disk. If single file is larger then split it up. You can do this in plain python. You don't even need pyspark.

@user238607 this is a good suggestion but it doesn't partition the data by date and hour, which can provide significant benefits in processing speed.

What is stopping you from implementing partition logic yourself?
